# sentence structure analysis

Tags: verbs, subjects

> **Of all these things Republican leaders made full and vigorous use, sometimes ascribing to the party, in accordance with ancient political usage, merits and achievements not wholly its own.**
>
> From *History of The United States* by Charles A. and Mary R. Beard

I have trouble analyzing the structure of this, even the subject and verb out of my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All these things" are the object that the subject "the Republican leaders" are acting upon.

Comment: Thank you very much. The preposition phrase "Of all these things" seems to belong to the phrasal verb "make use of." And "all these things" acts like an object of that verb phrase. Do you think it is right? If it is correct, is it possible to prepose the preposition phrase, like that? I think "All these things Republican leaders made full and vigorous use of" is grammatically correct. What do you think?

Comment: @nam Your alternate is fine. So would be the more natural *Republican leaders made full and vigorous of all these things.*